# in statement in for loop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c++

i have a for loop state ment as under:

```
    for(NSString* name in nameArray)
```

nameArray is NSArray.

In the above statement, what does it mean for: NSString* name in nameArray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through all NSString* in nameArray.
Can be written less cleanly:

```
for (int i=0;i<[nameArray count];++i) {
    NSString *name = [nameArray objectAtIndex:i];
    // Do stuff
}
```

Keep in mind: Don't iterate a mutable array and mutate it (and make sure no other thread does). In such a case you need to call `count` every iteration like displayed above.

Comment: Although the result will usually be the same, this code is not what the `in` syntax code compiles to. As @taskinoor mentioned, the `in` syntax is Objective-C 2.0 fast enumeration and it's considerably more complex and a lot faster. It also has a mutation guard so that an exception will be raised if you mutate the collection that's being iterated, which is much safer.

Answer (score 1):

This is fast enumeration syntax introduced in Objective-C 2.0. Check [this](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/fast-enumeration-on-the-iphone.html) tutorial for the details. Also you can Google "objective c fast enumeration" for many other resources available online.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the code inside the parenthesis will be executed for every object in the `nameArray`, which you will access through the `NSString *name` variable.